# Create a sql backup/dump with user permission but without Data

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2016. I would like to create a SQL Server backup/dump with  user permission but without Data so that I could import it to another SQL Server 2016 database for testing purpose

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can generate a script of your database without data

On SSMS, right click on database, then Tasks > Generate Scripts
Please check step by step details to [generate scripts for SQL Server database](http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-2012/how-to-script-data-in-sql-server-2012.aspx) but you will proceed without data option, by selection only schema as shown in following screenshot

[image]

On the same screen, there is also an other option "**Script Object-Level Permissions**", you can switch it to True

Comment: how about the user permission, will they be included in the script? i have tried generating one but seems there is no grant permission statement in it

Comment: There is also a second option to configure "Script Object-Level Permissions", I tested it and got GRANT commands in the output script

Comment: Thank You So Much